# How to display data in fixed width column in react

Tags: reactjs

I have created 5 columns for storing some data, but when the text inside one column is too long, the width will be changed.

Expect: The word will wrap to next line and each column width should stay the same.

https://playcode.io/1017243

Answer (score 0):

First you need set static width that you want.

```
width: '100px'
```

Then you just need break word property.

```
overflowWrap: 'break-word'
```

Should work as expected.

Comment: But if it added width to static, how can the 5 columns fill up the whole screen with same width? Like https://playcode.io/1017243

Comment: Remove all display: flex; on child divs and set max-width: 20vw; (1/5 window width).

Comment: What if the number of column is dynamic depends on api response. How can it be the same width for like 7,8 columns?

Comment: Then you can play with minWidth instead of maxWidth, but then you can't manage when text should go on new line, because you couldn't know every api response.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a `max-width` or `maxWidth` for your columns.
e.g:

```
style={{maxWidth: 100}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  style={{
              backgroundColor: 'navy',
              width: '100%',
              display: 'flex',
              whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
              overflowWrap: 'break-word'
            }}
```